# How to enter numbers into an array python?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm new at Python and I try to figure out of to enter a list of numbers into array.
This is what I did:
Ask the user for a number

```
iNum = int(input("Please enter your number: "))
```

Find the length

```
iLen=len(str(iNum))
```

Enter the digits into array

```
a=[]
for i in range(0,iLen,1):
    a[i].append=iNum%10
    iNum=iNum//10
```

it doesn't work and I can't understand why.. I even try to do a[i]=iNum%10.

so could you please assist?

Comment: Are you trying to store each digit of your string into list?

Comment: I need to take a number from the user, than print the count each digit is appear in the number. 
What want to do is to take the number and enter each digit into a[i] like in C++.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of confusing points to your code. What exactly is your end goal? You want all digits of a single number in the array? Or you want the user to enter multiple numbers?

Even with those things that confuse me there are still some things I can see are erroneous:

```
a[i].append=iNum%10
```

This is destined to fail right from the get-go: since `a` has been declared empty (`a = []`), there is no `a[i]` element. You can try this code out in an interactive environment like IDLE:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a[0] = 'hello'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    a[0] = 'hello'
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

You probably meant to call the `append` method on lists. However, to call that method, you don't use the equals sign, you use parenthesis. Something like so:

```
a.append(iNum % 10)
```

Another thing to note is your call to `range` is slightly superfluous. Since iterating from 0 to some number by a step of 1 is so common, it's the default.

```
range(iLen)
```

Putting it all together, we wind up with this:

```
a=[]
for i in range(iLen):
    a.append(iNum%10)
    iNum=iNum//10
```

If you want to get the digits of a single number into a list, you can simply use the `list` function on your string, like so:

```
>>> list('123')
['1', '2', '3']
```

And in Python, you can loop over the characters of a strings using the `for` loop. So if you want to convert each character to an integer, you can even do something like this:

```
a = []
for digit in str(iNum):
    a.append(int(digit))
```

Answer (score 1):

`.append()` is a method that appends items to the end of your list. The way you wrote it isn't correct:

```
a.append(iNum % 10)
```

A simpler way of doing what you're trying to do would be with a list comprehension:

```
number = input("Please enter your number: ")  # You want to keep it as a string
a = [int(digit) for digit in number]
```

Or even shorter with `map()`:

```
a = map(int, number)
```

Comment: Bear in mind that `input()` only returns a string in Python 3. In Python 2 you should use `raw_input()`

Comment: And in python3 map doesn't return a list.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to take a number from the user, than print the count each digit is appear in the number.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

n = input ("Please enter your number: ")

for digit in map (str, range (10) ):
    print ('{} appears {} times in your number.'. \
        format (digit, len ( [c for c in n if c == digit] ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

This: `a[i].append=iNum%10` is wrong because you bind the reference to a callable method to a `int` object. Apart from that, when you `append` to a list, it automatically inserts an object to the end of the list. If you would like to place something in a specific position inside a list, consider using the `insert()` method.

To instantly fix your code, call it like this: `a.append(iNum%10)`

Comment: When I do that, I get: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @YanivOfer Yeah, you're right, it was because I blindedly copied and pasted your code. Try running it now.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

```
sizeofarray=int(input())
arr=[]

for _ in range(sizeofarray):
    inputvalue = int(input("Enter value: "))
    arr.append(inputvalue)
```

or

Method 2:

```
arr=[int(i) for i in input().split()]

#Note For Method 2 the values in spaces example: 4 8 16 32 64 128 256
#The result array will look like this arr = [4,8,16,32,64,128,256]
```